# Magento change product attribute scope STORE to GLOBAL

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, scope

I added "test_att" attribute having scope is STORE VIEW. Now I want to change attribute scope to GLOBAL.

How I will achieve this updation?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that:

1) Go to the `Admin panel => Catalog => Attributes => Manage Attributes`.
http://joxi.ru/n2YaVlJtjDnbV2

2) Then navigate in the grid to your attribute (test_att).
http://joxi.ru/bmoz95KhM1Q9wr

3) And on the Properties tab select the scope you want.
http://joxi.ru/5mdY3y9Uvd63Z2